# Jquery .toggle() and the browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a fairly simple layout with a very strange outcome.

```
$(".main").on("hover", ".js_post", function () {
$(this).children('.js_del').toggle();
});
```

Essentially, when a user hovers over the .js_post div, the .js_del div is toggled.  Here's the css that hides .js_del:

```
.js_del { display:none; }
```

Now, when the cursor hovers over .js_post, the .js_del div toggles, as expected.  But, when the user clicks a link within the .js_post div and then clicks the browser back button, strange things happen...

In FF, all works as one would expect (i.e., the browser interprets the click as a mouseleave and toggles the .js_del.)

In Safari, however, when the user clicks back, the browser applies toggle in reverse (i.e., .js_del is showing and when the cursor hovers over .js_post, the .js_del link disappears.)

Even weirder...

I decide to add a handler to manually hide the .js_del div whenever an 'a' element within .js_post is clicked like this:

```
$(".js_post").find("a").click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.js_post').children('.js_del').hide();
});
```

And now, when viewed in Safari, all works as expected but in FF, it's reversed (i.e., .js_del is showing and when the cursor hovers over .js_post, the .js_del link disappears)!

Any thoughts???  Thanks!

Comment: I would make a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ of it :) more likely people will help

Comment: Well, since you shouldn't be using the "hover" pseudo event anyway (it's gone in 1.9), i'd suggest switching to mouseenter and mouseleave and two separate events, one that shows, the other that hides. This will prevent the toggle from getting out of sync with the events.

Comment: @PaulSullivan - I thought about jsfiddle but I don't think I can demonstrate clicking an a and then hitting browser back button...?

Comment: @KevinB - Good to know.  I'll update my production code to reflect 'hover' going away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the back button is not making the page cacheing behave the same, and you can't be sure of the dom element state, `toggle()` calls can be rough. I split out the mouseenter and mouseleave instead of `hover()`, and specifically called out the visibility within the child selector.  I also threw on a .hide() call at the very end to standardize the `.js_del` dom element visibility state regardless of back button browser issues.

## js

```
$(".main").on({
  "mouseenter":function(evt){
    $(this).children('.js_del:hidden').toggle();
  },
  "mouseleave":function(evt){
    $(this).children('.js_del:visible').toggle();
  }
}, ".js_post", null).find('.js_del:visible').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks!  That last part of throwing on the .hide(); call is what did the trick.  I was attaching the .hide() on a click handler but apparently I didn't need to go about it that way.